# c# How can I move a picturebox by a vScrollbar?

Tags: c#, object, scrollbar, move

I have a `pictureBox` in c# and I have to move it by a  `vScrollBar`.

It should be like this: (pseudo-code!)

```
        if (scrollbar.ScrollUp)
        {
            int i = 0;
            i += +1 per scroll
            pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, i);
        }

        if (scrollbar.ScrollDown)
        {
            int k = 0;
            k += -1 per scroll
            pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, k);
        }
```

[image]

I hope someone can understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: Put it in a Panel, set the panel's AutoScroll property to True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example for the MSDN [ScrollBar.Scroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx) event actually shows how to scroll a `PictureBox`.

Code from MSDN:

```
private void HandleScroll(Object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    //Create a graphics object and draw a portion of the image in the PictureBox.
    Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

    int xWidth = pictureBox1.Width;
    int yHeight = pictureBox1.Height;

    int x;
    int y;

    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
    {
        x = e.NewValue;
        y = vScrollBar1.Value;
    }
    else //e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll
    {
        y = e.NewValue;
        x = hScrollBar1.Value;
    }

    g.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,
      new Rectangle(0, 0, xWidth, yHeight),  //where to draw the image
      new Rectangle(x, y, xWidth, yHeight),  //the portion of the image to draw
      GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    pictureBox1.Update();
}
```

Where `HandleScroll` is the event handler for the `ScrollBar`'s `Scroll` event.

```
scrollBar1.Scroll += HandleScroll;
```

This is assuming you are trying to scroll the `PictureBox`.  If you really just want to move it around, you could try the following:

```
private void HandleScroll(Object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{   
    var diff = scrollBar1.Value - e.NewValue;

    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(diff, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
    }
    else //e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, diff);
    }
}
```

Warning, this code has not been tested.